# How can I fix "npm ERR! code1"

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, npm-install

I was trying to check some opensource projects to learn. I did npm install on terminal to dowload packages but i am getting this error and couldn't understand what caused error. I was an old project at the beginning it gave me the error of old packages and suggested me to update them, i deleted the old package-lock.json file and from pacgake.json i updated the dependencies.

I used "npm outdated --depth=3" to see which packages were missing.

```
Package                Current  Wanted  Latest  Location  Depended by
angular                MISSING   1.8.3   1.8.3  -         PlainCAT
angular-animate        MISSING   1.8.3   1.8.3  -         PlainCAT
angular-block-ui       MISSING   0.2.2   0.2.2  -         PlainCAT
angular-confirm1       MISSING   1.1.0   1.1.0  -         PlainCAT 
angular-sanitize       MISSING   1.8.3   1.8.3  -         PlainCAT
angular-toastr         MISSING   1.7.0   2.1.1  -         PlainCAT
angular-ui-bootstrap   MISSING   2.5.6   2.5.6  -         PlainCAT
bluebird               MISSING   3.7.2   3.7.2  -         PlainCAT
bootstrap              MISSING   3.4.1   5.1.3  -         PlainCAT
electron-context-menu  MISSING   0.9.1   3.1.2  -         PlainCAT
electron-is-dev        MISSING   0.3.0   2.0.0  -         PlainCAT
electron-search-text   MISSING   0.3.0   0.3.0  -         PlainCAT
jquery                 MISSING   2.2.4   3.6.0  -         PlainCAT
jschardet              MISSING   1.6.0   3.0.0  -         PlainCAT
node-cache             MISSING   4.2.1   5.1.2  -         PlainCAT
node-storage           MISSING   0.0.7   0.0.9  -         PlainCAT
nodehun                MISSING  2.0.12   3.0.2  -         PlainCAT
sha1-file              MISSING   1.0.4   3.0.0  -         PlainCAT
underscore             MISSING  1.13.3  1.13.3  -         PlainCAT
```

After i updated versions on package.json i tried "npm install" again but i get the error again.

> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer
> supported npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7
> or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain
> circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See
> https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details. npm WARN deprecated
> request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see
> https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm WARN deprecated
> angular-sanitize@1.8.3: For the actively supported Angular, see
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core. AngularJS support has
> officially ended. For extended AngularJS support options, see
> https://goo.gle/angularjs-path-forward. npm WARN deprecated
> angular-animate@1.8.3: For the actively supported Angular, see
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core. AngularJS support has
> officially ended. For extended AngularJS support options, see
> https://goo.gle/angularjs-path-forward. npm WARN deprecated
> angular@1.8.3: For the actively supported Angular, see
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core. AngularJS support has
> officially ended. For extended AngularJS support options, see
> https://goo.gle/angularjs-path-forward. npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path
> C:\Users\bugra\OneDrive\Desktop\bitirme projesi
> plaincat\PlainCAT\node_modules\nodehun npm ERR! command failed npm
> ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild npm
> ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok npm ERR! gyp info using
> node-gyp@6.1.0 npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64 npm
> ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.5 found at
> "C:\Users\bugra\anaconda3\python.exe" npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS npm
> ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm
> config npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in
> VS Command Prompt npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019
> (16.11.31727.386) found at: npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community" npm ERR! gyp ERR!
> find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features" npm ERR! gyp ERR!
> find VS - missing any VC++ toolset npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not
> find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use npm ERR! gyp ERR!
> find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not
> found npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only
> supported up to Node.js 8 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS npm ERR! gyp ERR!
> find VS **************************************************************
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of
> Visual Studio npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop
> development with C++" workload. npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more
> information consult the documentation at: npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
> https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows npm ERR! gyp ERR! find
> VS ************************************************************** npm
> ERR! gyp ERR! find VS npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error npm ERR! gyp
> ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail
> (C:\Users\bugra\OneDrive\Desktop\bitirme projesi
> plaincat\PlainCAT\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\bugra\OneDrive\Desktop\bitirme
> projesi
> plaincat\PlainCAT\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013
> (C:\Users\bugra\OneDrive\Desktop\bitirme projesi
> plaincat\PlainCAT\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\bugra\OneDrive\Desktop\bitirme
> projesi
> plaincat\PlainCAT\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\bugra\OneDrive\Desktop\bitirme
> projesi
> plaincat\PlainCAT\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\bugra\OneDrive\Desktop\bitirme
> projesi plaincat\PlainCAT\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7 npm
> ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\bugra\OneDrive\Desktop\bitirme
> projesi plaincat\PlainCAT\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16 npm
> ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler
> (node:child_process:406:5) npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at
> ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28) npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at
> maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16) npm ERR! gyp ERR!
> System Windows_NT 10.0.22000 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\bugra\OneDrive\Desktop\bitirme
> projesi plaincat\PlainCAT\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
> "rebuild" npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd
> C:\Users\bugra\OneDrive\Desktop\bitirme projesi
> plaincat\PlainCAT\node_modules\nodehun npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v
> v16.14.2 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\bugra\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-04-27T17_33_39_922Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Visual Studio as it states on the error message? And if installed, is it on the path?

Comment: I get this error on Visual Studio Code while i try npm install on terminal. I am not sure if it is related but i also have Visual Studio 2019 on my computer. About the path i did not see the visual studio on environment variables also i don't know how to add it.

Comment: You can try https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm